# When using MySQL INSERT -- ON DUPLICATE, how can one tell if MySQL ran INSERT or UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Pretty simple question really..

With PHP mysqli , i'm using INSERT INTO statement with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option

I there a way to easily tell if the query ran an INSERT or the UPDATE option?

I can pretty much do this by evaluating the insert_id, but is there a more "native" way to do this like a mysqli feedback?

Comment: Do you want to check weather the duplicate data is in the mysql or not

Comment: I don't think there's any way to tell. If you need to know, you should implement the logic yourself, with `SELECT` followed by `INSERT` or `UPDATE` depending on whether it found anything.

Comment: AFAIK, MySQL itself doesn't provide this information, so there's no way for `mysqli` to get it.

Comment: I just thought of something: you can call a stored procedure in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause. This could update another table that you could check afterward.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions guys... @bramar, that was my first go to thing, however i'll have to run this on a loop of 100 or more.. so i wanted to minimize the SQL queries .. hence using ON DUPLICATE routine..

anyway i think all this is a long way around .. i guess i'll just resort to fetching last_insert_id method.. tnx all

Comment: crap, i just tried it. apparently, the last_insert_id is defined the same way during a successful INSERT or UPDATE statement , lol. hmm.. trying to find another logic to this..